# Prove that if $Q^tQ = I$ and $A = QR$, then $\|Ax - b\| = \|Rx - Q^tb\|$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a linear algebra final tomorrow and was practicing a few proofs. I want to make sure this proof is correct.

> Prove that: If $Q^tQ = I$ and $A = QR$, then $\|Ax - b\| = \|Rx - Q^tb\|$
>
> $$\begin{align*}
> A &= QR\\[0.1cm]
> Ax &= QRx\\[0.1cm]
> Ax - b &= QRx - b\\[0.1cm]
> \qquad Ax - b &= QRx - QQ^tb \quad\text{(since $QQ^t = I$)}\\[0.1cm]
> Ax - b &= Q(Rx - Q^tb)\\[0.1cm]
> \|Ax - b\| &= \|Q(Rx - Q^tb)\|\\[0.1cm]
> \end{align*}$$
>   Since the orthogonal transformation preserves length, $\|Q(Rx - Q^tb)\| = \|(Rx - Q^tb)\|$.
>
> This completes the proof:
>
> $\|Ax - b\| = \|Rx - Q^tb\|$

Comment: [See here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for how to format mathematics on the site using MathJax.

Comment: Definitely will, still new to the site. Thanks!

Comment: Your proof looks good.

Comment: One of my doubts was that I do not know if this implication holds true for all matrices:

If Q^tQ = I, then QQ^t = I as well.

Comment: @AlexanderVentura Since $Q$ is a square matrix, the left inverse is the same as right inverse and hence $Q^TQ = I \implies QQ^T = I$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This CW answer intends to remove the question from the unanswered queue.*

---

As copper.hat already noted in the comments, your proof looks good. Also $QQ^T=I$ follows from $Q^TQ=I$ since $Q$ is a square matrix (and hence left and right inverses agree). This was noted by user17762 in the comments.